# Consecutive calls callback called more times than expected

Tags: php, phpunit

Before I ask this question please keep in mind this is a greatly simplified version of my actual test case.

I am mocking an interface with the purposes of collecting the arguments a certain method was called with. Here is my code:

```
interface NormalInterface {
 public function functionWithOneParameter($parameter);
}  

class NormalInterfaceTest {
    public function testBasicMockCallback() {
        $mock = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(NormalInterface::class);
        $names = [];
        $cb = function ($name) use (&$names) {
           $names[] = basename($name);
           return true;
        };
        $mock->expects($this->exactly(4))
            ->method("functionWithOneParameter")
            ->withConsecutive([ $this->callback($cb) ],[ $this->callback($cb) ],[ $this->callback($cb) ],[ $this->callback($cb) ])
            ->willReturn(true,true, true, true);
       $mock->functionWithOneParameter("one");
       $mock->functionWithOneParameter("two");
       $mock->functionWithOneParameter("three");
       $mock->functionWithOneParameter("four");
       // If the test ends here it works fine
       $this->assertCount(4, $names); 
   }
}
```

The above test works without line `$this->assertCount(4, $names)` which means that the mock method is called exactly 4 times.

However with that line I get:

> Failed asserting that actual size 14 matches expected size 4.

The actual content of `$names` is:

```
array:14 [
  0 => "one", 
  1 => "one", 2 => "two",
  3 => "one", 4 => "two", 5 => "three"
  6 => "one", 7 => "two", 8 => "three", 9 => "four"
  10 => "one", 11 => "two", 12 => "three", 13 => "four"
]
```

I would think that the callback would be called 4 times one for each function call, but apparently it is called 14 times. Am I doing something wrong? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how this is working?

**Update:**

The issue is resolved if I replace the `withConsecutive` with a simple: `with($this->callback($cb))->willRetrurn(true)` which in this particular case is equivalent but in the cases where I want each consecutive call do check something different this will not work. I feel like I'm missing something very fundamental about either how PHPUnit tests consecutive call parameters.